# Ubuntu Release Calendar, is it maintained?

Tags: release-management, calendar

I am subscribed to the [Ubuntu Release Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=ab54tjqqlaol3rdnksieju8mcc@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Etc/GMT). But recently, it seems that all of the events there have disappeared. Is it being shut down or something? Is there any alternative with Ubuntu releases and key events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raring Ringtail schedule is available here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseSchedule

The overall release schedule roster is available here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseSchedule

Maintenance is occurring as the Ringtail schedule was last updated by Dave Walker on March 7th and the overall schedule roster need not be updated until May 2013 at the earliest.  The calendar on the Wiki infrastructure is authoritative.  The former release manager Kate Stewart, during the course of her employment at Canonical, appears to have maintained that calendar herself but since she is no longer employed by Canonical that calendar is no longer maintained

Comment: You seem to be missing the point.  He's pointing to a google calendar asking if it is actively updated.  I put my answer in as a stop-gap until someone that knows can answer with if the google-calendar is updated or not.

Comment: Well, digging around for a couple moments on that calendar showed that it was maintained by Kate Stewart while she was employed by Canonical.  Kate's wiki bio has that period of employment in the past tense so it looks like no, it isn't going to be maintained.  I can't seem to find when she stopped being employed by Canonical, alas.

Comment: If you move that into the answer you'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: Thanks. Well, may I suggest that Canonical puts somebody on its maintenance? :D